# The KeyValuePair array is not working in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In the controller I have KeyValuePair variable:

```
KeyValuePair<int, string>[] kvp= new KeyValuePair<int, string>[6];
            kvp[0] = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "a");
…

ViewData["kvp"] = kvp;
```

In the View I cannot declare the keyValuePair:

```
@model IslForu.Pages.PersonalPage.DiscussionDetail

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Hello";    
}
@{             
   var kvp = @ViewData["kvp"] as KeyValuePair<int, string>[];              
 }
… <p> kvp[i]  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use ViewBag instead of ViewData

controller:

```
ViewBag.kvp = kvp;
```

View:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Hello";
}

<p> @ViewBag.kvp[0]  </p>
```

---

or change yourcode to

```
 @{             
   var kvp = ViewData["kvp"] as KeyValuePair<int, string>[];              
 }
 <p> @kvp[0]  </p>
```

Comment: var kvp = ViewData["kvp"] as KeyValuePair<int, string>[]; - is not accepted by VS

Comment: Also there is no ViewBag in asp.net core???

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: How to activate ViewBag in PageModel of asp.net core?

Answer (score 0):

you are not using @ correctly, should be

```
@{             
   var kvp = ViewData["kvp"] as KeyValuePair<int, string>[]>; // not @ViewData["kvp"]             
 }

<p> @kvp[0].Value  </p> // not @kvp[0]
```

Comment: Serge, there is an error in your declaration: "The "int," element was not closed.  All elements must be either self-closing or have a matching end tag."

Comment: @AbuBakr Thank you , it is a serious error that nobody would ever find

Comment: Hahaha you are right! Do you know how to activate ViewBag in PageModel (x.cshtml.cs files) of asp.net core? Thanks